# Need help removing HTML tags, certain punctuation, and ending periods

Tags: regex, r

Suppose I have this test string:

```
test.string <- c("This is just a <test> string. I'm trying to see, if a FN will remove certain things like </HTML tags>, periods; but not the one in ASP.net, for example.")
```

I want to:

1. Remove anything contained within an html tag
2. Remove certain punctuation (,:;)
3. Period that end a sentence.

So the above should be:

```
c("This is just a string I'm trying to see if a FN will remove certain things like periods but not the one in ASP.net for example")
```

For #1, I've tried the following:

```
gsub("<.*?>", "", x, perl = FALSE)
```

And that seems to work OK.

For #2, I think it's simply:

```
gsub("[:@$%&*:,;^():]", "", x, perl = FALSE)
```

Which works.

For #3, I tried:

```
gsub("+[:alpha:]?[.]+[:space:]", "", test.string, perl = FALSE)
```

But that didn't work...

Any ideas on where I went wrong? I totally suck at RegExp, so any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: When you say "end a sentence", do you mean end a string? If so, `gsub("\\.$", "", test.string)` is sufficient; if not, how do you define a sentence?

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to remove all period's "." that are either at the end of the input string (your `gsub` above works) *OR*, followed by a space AND after 1-or-more alphanumeric characters. So in the example, the only period left, should be the one in `"ASP.net"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your provided input and rules for what you want removed, the following should work.

```
gsub('\\s*<.*?>|[:;,]|(?<=[a-zA-Z])\\.(?=\\s|$)', '', test.string, perl=T)
```

See [**Working Demo**](http://ideone.com/D7bS0j)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
test.string <- "There is a natural aristocracy among men. The grounds of this are virtue and talents. "

gsub("\\.\\s*", "", gsub("([a-zA-Z0-9]). ([A-Z])", "\\1 \\2", test.string))
# "There is a natural aristocracy among men The grounds of this are virtue and talents
```